# how to use mysql in xampp that works both on local and server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'v been having a problem and i didn't find anything by Googleing it!
The scenario is as follows...
I installed `xampp` and use it to develop my website in php! I wrote .php codes in my `htdocs` folder, test it locally by `localhost/` and when it works correctly, i upload it to web-server using `FileZilla`. Everything works perfect!
The problem is that I use MySQL php commands like `mysql_connect(...)` in my local files, and it gives me error in local test browser (because the connection name/pass and databases is different from what it should be on server), but it works OK on server side!
So, the problem is when MySQL commands come into play, I can't test it locally then publish it to server.
(I use `phpMyAdmin` to configure databases in both local and server side.)
One solution would be to have 2 different folder, one for local test, and one for server. but every time I change a file in local folder, I should go and change it in another folder, then upload it... which is a nightmare!!
Other solution that i'm currently using is simply i upload every change and test it on server! which i think it's not correct!
I really appreciate any suggestion to work around this problem!

Comment: Store the database credentials in some kind of settings file keeping a different one on the server. In other words the username/pass and so on that is used to connect to the server is loaded from a configuration file.

Comment: so, this configuration file is the only difference between local and server and it should not be uploaded! right?

Comment: That's correct=) When I'm using a system such as `git` I always ignore these kind of setting files, because each developer will have a custom one.